# Blurry zones in Windows 10 without scaling enabled

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, resolution, font-smoothing

It has been a while and appeared at a precise point in time some months ago.

'Unused' zones are being progressively blurred on my main screen (1080p, I have another smaller monitor) and it unblurs when the zones get activated (mouse hover, screenshot, etc.) so I cannot join a screenshot <del>(the effect is not visible enough on phone pictures)</del>. It is clear it is a software issue because the zones are always clear well defined as rectangles and I couldn't find patterns in the zones.

I looked all over windows' display settings and NVidia control panel settings and fiddled with it but nothing made it disappear or change behaviour.

It appears to exist only in certain applications (web browsers mainly, but not only) and doesn't appear in games for instance. Applications using Electron are very impacted, for instance Github Desktop client

Any idea what it could be linked to ?

EDIT : I could take a semi-decent picture you can find [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoKtc.jpg). Pretty impressive how blurry it can get ! Also, I managed to [take a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJJP1.jpg) showing the border between a blurred and a non-blurred zone. [Another one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dF0uA.jpg)

Comment: If it helps, screenshots using the shortcut Win+Shift+S do actually work but screenshots using the screen capture native tool doesn't !

Comment: That looks terrible. It is almost certainly related to hardware-accelerated 2D. Have you tried updating your graphics driver? Is this perhaps a laptop with switchable graphics?

Comment: This is a quite new desktop equipped with a GTX1080 and its latest drivers. I can give complete specs if needed

Comment: Hm, okay. Try some older drivers then! It could always be a bug introduced recently.

Comment: I just reinstalled the latest driver and, no luck. I will update here if I get any results with older drivers

Comment: I installed an old driver, which asked me if I wanted to wipe my settings. And indeed, after doing so the problem went away ! I just reinstalled the last version of the drivers and there seems to be no problem anymore. Now, to the settings !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to disable FXAA in the NVidia settings panel. A reboot is required for the change to take effect so it was difficult to troubleshoot. Hope it helps someone !

Comment: Thanks, this was it.